# How to give external mobile apps access to XPages REST services via oAuth

Tags: xpages, ibm-sbt

I believe the recent version of SBT does not include controls to let Domino act as OAuth provider. Are there any plans?

My client likes to provide authenticated REST calls to external mobile apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SBT provides you classes to act as an OAuth client, not to build an OAuth provider. That said, there is some work going on in this area by the core Domino team. I cannot commit on any plan, but I heard that it might be an add-on to 9.0...

Comment: That would be great, so Apps could integrate authenticated content of Domino / XWork server more easily

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not native, however, Matt White has written an article with code to show how to do this. It may be something that you can use to provide the functionality? See more: http://mattwhite.me/2010/10/20/how-to-get-sso-for-facebook-working-with-xpages.html